# Suggestion about dealing with subqueries that need string analysis

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I need to create a query on the fly through VBA that get some strings from a table based on a set of criteria selected by the user . From the results of that first query I need to find the position of certain characters in the strings and only select the one that have the characters at a given position. This need to be done quickly as it then needs to be displayed in a combo box for the user to select before he runs a full other query.

So my question is what is the fastest/best way to do this ?

Should I put the result of the first query in a temporary table , analyze the strings from that table, delete the records that don't meet the selection and then run a query to display in the combo box from that table ?

Thank you

Comment: Please show us an example of that you're after here: *"select the one that have the characters at a given position"*

Comment: Depending on actual data (more detail please), I would pull the data from database where text field contains the character regardless of position in the string, then analyze / filter your results in VBA using whatever methodology works best.

Comment: It is actually more complicated than just finding the position of the characters. Here is and example of a string that has been pooled out of the database based on the fact that it has HEDC in the string. HEDC:Cholesterol:DOPC:DOPE_5:30:2:5 now I have to analyze the string and get the number that correspond to the same position HEDC is in the string (for example here it would be the first number after the _.  To analyze it I was thinking of splitting the string in an array and work from there.  So probably working from a temporary table is best right ?

Comment: Does the table field always include 4 string values separated by colons, followed by one underscore, and finally 4 numbers separated by colons?

Comment: not always 4 (can be 4, 5, 6 or 7), but the number of string values separated by colons before the underscore is always the same as the number of numbers separated by colons after the underscore.

Comment: Consider a custom VBA function to extract the value of interest from your input string.  I don't think a solution based on a temporary table would be any better.